# Finding boundary coordinates of user current location with a given radius

Tags: geojson, coordinates, latitude-longitude, boundaries, node-js

I have my current lat and lng details

```
{
        "lat": 8.561032,
        "lng": 76.846333
}
```

And from this I need to build a boundary around me with given radius.
So How can I get the boundary coordinates for that?

I'm working with JavaScript - NodeJs

Comment: You could use turf.js library: http://turfjs.org/docs/